# Fill the form as drop down element is selected in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my event method for drop down. I need to display all record from database as selected any element from drop down list. But the following code is not working. Can you suggest any solution in the same.

```
protected void DropDownListSelectEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string q = "select uid,fname,mname,lname,date_format(hire_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),desg,date_format(dob,'%Y-%m-%d'),AddressLine1,AddressLine2,state,city,pincode,country,MobileNo,UserActive,username,date_format(annivarsary,'%Y-%m-%d'),email from nWorksUser where Username='" + DropDownListSelectEmployee.Text + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q,conn);
                conn.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(q, conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {

                    txtFirstName.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                    txtMiddleName.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                    txtLastName.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                    txtMobile.Text = dr[13].ToString();
                    txtUsername.Text = dr[15].ToString();
                    txtState.Text = dr[9].ToString(); 
                    txtPincode.Text = dr[11].ToString();
                    txtEmail.Text = dr[17].ToString();
                    txtDob.Text = dr[6].ToString();
                    txtDesignation.Text = dr[5].ToString();
                    txtDateofHire.Text = dr[4].ToString();
                    txtDateofAnnivarsary.Text = dr[16].ToString();
                    txtCountry.Text = dr[12].ToString();
                    txtCity.Text = dr[10].ToString();
                    txtAddressLine2.Text = dr[7].ToString();
                    txtAddressLine1.Text = dr[8].ToString();                

                    if(dr[14].ToString().Length==4)
                    {
                        RdoGender.SelectedIndex = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RdoGender.SelectedIndex = 2;
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
```

asp code :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EmployeeManagementForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebAPP.EmployeeManagementForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <link href="Content/MyStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <header>
                <h1>Employee Management</h1>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonLogOut" runat="server" Text="Log Out" class="btnLogout" />
            </header>

            <nav>
                <button id="btnAttendance"             onclick="window.location.href='AttendanceForm.aspx';return false;"         class="btn">Attendance</button><br />
                <button id="ButtonOnBoardEmployee"     onclick="window.location.href='OnBoardEmployeeForm.aspx';return false;"    class="btn">On Board Employee</button><br />
                <button id="ButtonEmployeeManagement"  onclick="window.location.href='EmployeeManagementForm.aspx';return false;" class="btn">Employee Management</button><br />
                <button id="ButtonAdministration"      onclick="window.location.href='AdministrationForm.aspx';return false;"     class="btn" >Administration</button><br />
                <button id="ButtonAdminManagement"     onclick="window.location.href='AdminManagementForm.aspx';return false;"    class="btn" >Admin Management</button><br />
                <button id="ButtonEventCalendar"       onclick="window.location.href='EventCalendarForm.aspx';return false;"      class="btn" >Event Calendar</button><br />            
            </nav>
            <div>
                <table style="border: 1pt solid #6666FF; width: 82.9%; height: 924px; font-family: Verdana;
                    border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;" class="style12" colspan="3">
                            <asp:Label ID="lableMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; height: 50px;" colspan="3" class="style9">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Text="Modification Form" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>                           
                        <td  class="style11" style="text-align: center;" colspan="3"> 
                        <b>Select Employee : </b>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSelectEmployee" runat="server" 
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListSelectEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem>nWorks Employee</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>                   
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">

                            <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvFirstName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Middle Name :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMiddleName" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtMiddleName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text="Last Name :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvLastName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtLastName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="E-Mail :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvUserName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            &nbsp;<br />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RxvEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
                                ErrorMessage="Invalid E-mail" ForeColor="#FF3300" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Username :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtUsername"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvPwd" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmPwd" runat="server" Text="Confirm Pasword :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvCnfrmPwd" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPwd"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <br />
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CvCnfmPwd" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password and Confirm Password didnt matched"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToCompare="txtPassword" ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPwd"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDob" runat="server" Text="Date of Birth :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDob" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="(dd/mm/yyyy)"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtDob"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            &nbsp;<br />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RxvDob" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDob"
                                ErrorMessage="Invalid Date Format" ValidationExpression="^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31\/((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)\/((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))\/((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29\/02\/(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right;" class="style11">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMobile" runat="server" Text="Mobile"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4">
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RxvMobile" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Mobile Number"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ValidationExpression="^([7-9]{1})([0-9]{9})$" ControlToValidate="txtMobile"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text="Address Line 1:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressLine1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvAddress" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtAddressLine1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Address Line 2:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressLine2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="City :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtCity"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="State :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtState"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Country :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtCountry"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Pin Code :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPincode" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtPincode"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Date of Hire :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateofHire" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="(dd/mm/yyyy)"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtDateofHire"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            &nbsp;<br />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateofHire"
                                ErrorMessage="Invalid Date Format" ValidationExpression="^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31\/((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)\/((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))\/((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29\/02\/(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Date of Annivarsary :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateofAnnivarsary" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="(dd/mm/yyyy)"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;<br />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateofAnnivarsary"
                                ErrorMessage="Invalid Date Format" ValidationExpression="^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31\/((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)\/((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))\/((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29\/02\/(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Designation :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesignation" runat="server" Class="style9"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtDesignation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblGender" runat="server" Text="Gender :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RdoGender" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="176px">
                                <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvGender" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="RdoGender"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td  class="style11" style="text-align: right;">Employee Status :</td>
                        <td  class="style11" style="text-align: left;"> 
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonsEmployeeStatus" runat="server"  
                                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonsEmployeeStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                                <asp:ListItem>Inactive</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Active</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
                        <td  class="style11" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmpInactivatedDate" runat="server" Class="style9" AutoPostBack= "True"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;" class="style12">&nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td class="style12" style="text-align: left;">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" class="btnsLikeSubmit"
                                 />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" class="btnsLikeSubmit"
                                Text="Clear" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;" class="style7"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>

                    </table>




            <footer>
                Copyright © nWorks.co
            </footer>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "is not working"?

Comment: looks like you overwriting all `TextBox` elements each iteration instead of  display all records

Comment: Nothing is happening on selection of element from drop down list

Comment: Have you used the debugger? Why you use single controls if you have multiple result records? Normally you use a control like `GridView`.

Comment: conn : MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("uid=root;pwd=root;server=localhost;database=newcompanydatabase;");

Comment: If some one wants to edit there profile, user will select his name from database and form will be filled. so that he will be able to make changes in that and save it again. Same C# logic worked in wpf app. Actually I am converting wpf to webapp.

Comment: I solve this problem my selves  by adding AutoPostBack="true" but drop down list showing unexpected behave like select any element from drop down it only accept first element of drop down list. Can you help in that?